# Importing multiple multi module projects as maven project at once in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2eclipse

My workspace contains more than 100 maven projects and at a time I only need to import around 70 projects in workspace. 
[Please check this image I attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A99On.png) m2e shows the project hierarchy based on dependency. What I have to do now is select every project pom, which I want to import. 
So is there any way by which we can specify a list of project that can be imported as maven project rather than selecting required project manually.

Comment: Can't see any image in the question, maybe you forgot it.

Comment: As I am new user, stack overflow not allowed to add image directly. you can click on "Workspace project hierarchy" URL to see the image. Thanks

Comment: The question is not really clear to me. Do you import the projects more than once? Why is it easier to have an external list instead of choosing the relevant projects from the import wizard?

Comment: Ya I mean we need to do workspace setup frequently among teams, so every time, they have to look up into some file like which project pom to select and which not while importing, which is kind of frustrating work. So I just want to know if there is some alternative for this. Thanks

Comment: Can't you just zip a standard workspace and use it for new eclipse setups?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried File -> Import -> Maven -> Existing Maven Projects? You specify directory where all your projects are and eclipse will automatically detects all maven projects underneath it. You can then select All or select them individually. In your case you can select All and then deselect 30 which you don't need.

PS - this assume you have m2eclipse plugin install. If not you can install it or eclipse might just prompt you to install one when you try above steps.

Comment: even I select just one subproject, but all subproject is finally imported in my workspace...

Comment: have you tried deselecting top level pom.xml and selecting only leaf level pom.xml (projects) that you need? btw based on your screenshot it seems m2e already detecting all maven projects under the path you gave automatically.